# Помогите решить проблему с ботом в Telegram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Мой код:

```py
import telebot


from telebot import types
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

def start_markup():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=True)
    link_keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1-й канал", url="https://t.me/fdfdfdf")
    link_keyboard2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="2-й канал", url="https://t.me/fdfdfdf")
    link_keyboard3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="3-й канал", url="https://t.me/fdfdfdf")
    check_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Проверить",callback_data="check")
    markup.add(link_keyboard1,link_keyboard2,link_keyboard3,check_keyboard)
    return markup

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.chat_id
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Привет, {0.first_name} !\n"
                              "Чтобы пользоваться ботом подпишитесь на каналы !",reply_markup=start_markup())


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

При запуске выдаёт ошибку:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
    line 19, in start
        chat_id = message.chat_id
AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'chat_id'
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: надо текст ошибки перевести или в чем вопрос? Справа - восемь ссылок на вопросы с точно такой же ошибкой.

Comment: Отвечает ли это на ваш вопрос? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305978/attributeerror-message-object-has-no-attribute-chat-id

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [AttributeError: 'Message' object has no attribute 'chat\_id'](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1305978/attributeerror-message-object-has-no-attribute-chat-id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что вы обращаетесь к несуществующему параметру chat_id объекта Message. Если вы хотите получить ID чата, то сделать это можно так: `message.chat.id`.
Т. е. код станет таким:

```py
import telebot


from telebot import types
 
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")

def start_markup():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=True)
    link_keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="1-й канал", url="https://t.me/fdfdfdf")
    link_keyboard2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="2-й канал", url="https://t.me/fdfdfdf")
    link_keyboard3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="3-й канал", url="https://t.me/fdfdfdf")
    check_keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Проверить",callback_data="check")
    markup.add(link_keyboard1,link_keyboard2,link_keyboard3,check_keyboard)
    return markup

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    first_name = message.chat.first_name
    bot.send_message(chat_id, "Привет, {0.first_name} !\n"
                              "Чтобы пользоваться ботом подпишитесь на каналы !",reply_markup=start_markup())

# и.т.д
```